# null pointer expection in IE and not in Firefox, why does this happen?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I have script that loops through an array of html tag id's, some elements in the array are empty. I have an if statement that works fine in Firefox but throws a null pointer or not an object error in IE

```
if((storedVars.id) != ("")){selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().document.getElementById(storedVars.id).type;}
```

why does it fail in IE and not in firefox and what is the proper syntax for IE?

Comment: What version(s) of IE? What's the `id` it's failing on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IE it might be undefined or `null` rather than empty string, so try this instead:

```
if(storedVars.id && storedVars.id !== "")
```

(also bit more efficient due to `!==` operator comparing two strings)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that if storedVars.id == null, then this code won't work, regardless of browser.  That's because storedVars.id != ("") is true when storedVars.id is null.  Maybe it's null in IE (or the tests that you run in IE) and not null in Firefox.  The root cause of that might be somewhere else in your code.  Assuming it's not null, and assuming the other objects all exist and aren't null (selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow()) and are returning cross-browser compatible objects, then this code should execute.

But, as far as I can tell, this code doesn't do anything.  There's no method call or assignment.  A little off topic but to ease all this cross browser pain, people usually just use a framework like jQuery or YUI.